# Most efficient way of adding elements given the index list in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, addition

Assume we have a numpy array A with shape (N, ) and a matrix D with shape (M, 3) which has data and another matrix I with shape (M, 3) which has corresponding index of each data element in D. How can we construct A given D and I such that the repeated element indexes are added?

Example:

```
############# A[I] := D ###################################  
A = [0.5, 0.6]                         # Final Reduced Data Vector
D = [[0.1, 0.1 0.2], [0.2, 0.4, 0.1]]  # Data
I = [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]]             # Indices
```

For example:

```
A[0] = D[0][0] + D[0][2] + D[1][0]     # 0.5 = 0.1 + 0.2 + 0.2
```

Since in index matrix we have:

```
I[0][0] = I[0][2] = I[1][0] = 0
```

Target is to avoid looping over all elements to be efficient for large N, M (10^6-10^9).

Comment: Question needs more clarification. What do you mean "repeated element indexes are added"? Are you getting `0.5` by doing `0.1+0.4`? If so how are you getting `0.6`?

Comment: I added more explanation, please let me know if it is clear now.

Comment: Iterate over `I` and add `A[I[x][y]] += D[x][y]`

Comment: Are all indices guaranteed to appear at least once in `I`?

Comment: Yes, I can add that assumption (or modify original D and I)

Comment: On second thought it doesn't matter

Comment: M does not matter though - what MIGHT matter is the number of integers in `I`

Comment: If you don't have so much **unique** values in `I`, you can do: `np.array([D[I==idx].sum() for idx in np.unique(I)])`. It'll iterate only for unique indexes (twice in your example).

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. I don't know why I said that. I meant to say it does not matter whether it is `(M,3)` or `(M/2,1)` since we're flattening it anyway. The number of unique integers in `I` also matters (which if we assume all indices is guranteed to appear at least once in `I`, then it is simply `N`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt you can get much faster than `np.bincount` - and notice how the [official documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) provides this exact usecase

```
# Your example
A = [0.5, 0.6]
D = [[0.1, 0.1, 0.2], [0.2, 0.4, 0.1]]
I = [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]]

# Solution
import numpy as np    
D, I = np.array(D).flatten(), np.array(I).flatten()
print(np.bincount(I, D)) #[0.5 0.6]
```

Comment: On a second look, using ravel instead of flatten might give us a slight boost in performance here,  but I don't think that's very relevant relative to the actual binning and counting phase.

Answer (score 3):

The shape of `I` and `D` doesn't matter: you can clearly ravel the arrays without changing the outcome:

```
index = np.ravel(I)
data = np.ravel(D)
```

Now you can sort both arrays according to `I`:

```
sorter = np.argsort(index)
index = index[sorter]
data = data[sorter]
```

This is helpful because now `index` looks like this:

```
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1
```

And `data` is this:

```
0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1
```

Adding together runs of consecutive numbers should be easier than processing random locations. Let's start by finding the indices where the runs start:

```
runs = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(index)) + 1]
```

Now you can use the fact that ufuncs like `np.add` have a partial `reduce` operation called `reduceat`. This allows you to sum regions of an array:

```
a = np.add.reduceat(data, runs)
```

If `I` is guaranteed to contain all indices in [0, `A.size`) at least once, you're done: just assign to `A` instead of `a`. If not, you can make the mapping using the fact that the start of each run in `index` is the target index:

```
A = np.zeros(n)
A[index[runs]] = a
```

**Algorithmic complexity analysis:**

- `ravel` is O(1) in time and space if the data is in an array. If it's a list, this is O(MN) in time and space
- `argsort` is O(MN log MN) in time and `O(MN)` in space
- Indexing by `sorter` is O(MN) in time and space
- Computing `runs` is O(MN) in time and O(MN + M) = O(MN) in space
- `reduceat` is a single pass: O(MN) in time, O(M) in space
- Reassigning `A` is O(M) in time and space

Total: O(MN log MN) time, O(MN) space

**TL;DR**

```
def make_A(D, I, M):
    index = np.ravel(I)
    data = np.ravel(D)
    sorter = np.argsort(index)
    index = index[sorter]

    if index[0] < 0 or index[-1] >= M:
        raise ValueError('Bad indices')

    data = data[sorter]
    runs = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(index)) + 1]
    a = np.add.reduceat(data, runs)
    if a.size == M:
        return a
    A = np.zeros(M)
    A[index[runs]] = a
    return A
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very smart way to do it, I would just wait few days in case, someone finds more efficient algorithm.

Comment: Take your time. You theoretically do this faster using a hash table, since that has O(1) lookup time, but I suspect your data isn't large enough for the savings in complexity to overtake the overhead of python function calls.

Comment: @Roy. Made a couple of typo fixes. Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

If you know the size of A beforehand, as it seems you do, you can simply use [add.at](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

```
import numpy as np

D = [[0.1, 0.1, 0.2], [0.2, 0.4, 0.1]]
I = [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]]

arr_D = np.array(D)
arr_I = np.array(I)

A = np.zeros(2)

np.add.at(A, arr_I, arr_D)

print(A)
```

**Output**

```
[0.5 0.6]
```

If you don't know the size of A, you can use [max](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html) to compute it:

```
A = np.zeros(arr_I.max() + 1)
np.add.at(A, arr_I, arr_D)
print(A)
```

**Output**

```
[0.5 0.6]
```

The time complexity of this algorithm is *O(N)*, with also space complexity *O(N)*.

The:

```
arr_I.max() + 1
```

is what bincount does under the hood, from the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html):

> The result of binning the input array. The length of out is equal to
> np.amax(x)+1.

That being said, bincount is at least one order of magnitude faster:

```
I = np.random.choice(1000, size=(1000, 3), replace=True)
D = np.random.random((1000, 3))
%timeit make_A_with_at(I, D, 1000)
213 µs ± 25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit make_A_with_bincount(I, D)
11 µs ± 15.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation and timing.